# How to trace the ethereum in a contract if messages are not written in the blockchain

Tags: transactions, message

The messages initiated by contracts are not stored in the blockchain, unlike transactions. If that's the case how can do we see where an ethereum in a contract or a wallet came from if it's from a contract?

Comment: I don't have the answer. But working like this is not a good idea as in the futur, the devs want that "classical" addresses and contracts to be impossible to distinct (because they are basicaly the same)